# How to Deploy a Lambda Layer Created in .NET 6.0 & C# Using AWS CDK?

Tags: .net-6.0, aws-cdk, aws-cdk-typescript

I'm want to deploy a Lambda Layer created in .NET 6 and C# using AWS CDK and use it in .Net 6 lambda functions.

Able to create it but it is giving error -

> ```
> Could not load file or assembly 'TestS3Layer, Version=1.0.0.0
> ```

TestS3Layer is the layer DLL that has been used in lambda function.

Below steps has been performed:

- **Using CDK deployed Layer & Lambda function:**

---

Deployed a .Net 6 lambda layer using AWS CDK. See below code.

```
const TestS3Layer = new lambda.LayerVersion(this, 'TestS3Layer', {
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('G:/POC/TestS3Layer/bin/Release/net6.0/'),
    compatibleRuntimes: [lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6],
    description: 'Layer created via AWs CDK.',
});
```

[Layer DLLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cGzu.png) for reference.

---

Created .Net 6 lambda function which contains code to generate some random data and pass those data to TestS3layer as a stream to upload in S3 bucket.

Deploy the lambda function and assign the same layer to the lambda function using AWS CDK. See below code:

```
// Create lambda function
const myFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6,
    handler: 'TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction::TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction.Function::FunctionHandler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('G:/POC/TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction/src/TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction/bin/Release/net6.0/'),
    memorySize: 256,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
    role: existingRole,
    description: ".Net 6 Lambda function deployed using AWS CDK.",
    layers: [TestS3Layer]
});
```

Lambda function deployed and layer integrated, Great!

Test it via AWS console test event. Gives error as below:

> ```
> "cause": {
>     "errorType": "FileNotFoundException",
>     "errorMessage": "Could not load file or assembly 'TestS3Layer, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.\n",
>     "stackTrace": [
>       "at TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction.Function..ctor()",
>       "at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean wrapExceptions)"
>     ]
>   }
> ```

---

- **Layer deployed via CLI command and Lambda function deployed via CDK:**

Use command -

```
dotnet lambda publish-layer --region region-name --layer-name layer-name --layer-type runtime-package-store -sb s3-bucket-name -f net6.0 --package-manifest manifest.xml
```

This will publish the layer with the **layer-type as runtime package store**.

The folder structure of the deployed layer files will be as below: (example of AWSSDK.S3 dll)

**\dotnetcore\store\x64\net6.0\awssdk.s3\3.7.201.12\lib\netcoreapp3.1\AWSSDK.S3.dll**

---

#### [What is Runtime Package Store?](https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/blob/master/docs/Layers.md#what-is-runtime-package-store)

One of the major goals of Lambda layers was to bundle up your function's dependencies separately so that the dependencies didn't have to be upload every time you changed your code and deployed a new Lambda function version.

.NET Core is not designed to simply load assemblies from a directory outside of the deployment bundle. All dependencies have to be known about during the `dotnet publish` point and the ***.NET Core runtime needs to know about all the directories with assemblies at start up time.***

To solve these challenges for .NET Core the AWS .NET tooling uses .NET Core's **[Runtime package stores](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/runtime-store)** feature.

---

As mentioned in above block that "***.NET Core runtime needs to know about all the directories with assemblies at start up time***" it uses environment variable in lambda function to know that where to find the assemblies.

environment variable - **DOTNET_SHARED_STORE: '/opt/dotnetcore/store/'** refer [link](https://github.com/aws/aws-extensions-for-dotnet-cli/blob/master/docs/Layers.md) for more details.

Now, deploy the lambda function and use layer ARN to bind with lambda function + pass the environment variable while deployment. See below code.

```
// Existing Lambda Layer ARN
const existingLayerArn = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:123456789012:layer:TestS3Layer:1';

// Lambda function
const myFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction', {
    runtime: lambda.Runtime.DOTNET_6,
    handler: 'TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction::TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction.Function::FunctionHandler',
    code: lambda.Code.fromAsset('G:/POC/TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction/src/TestLambdaLayerIntegrationFunction/bin/Release/net6.0/'),
    memorySize: 256,
    timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(60),
    role: existingRole,
    environment: {
      DOTNET_SHARED_STORE: '/opt/dotnetcore/store/',
    },
    description: ".Net 6 Lambda function deployed using AWS CDK.",
    layers: [lambda.LayerVersion.fromLayerVersionArn(this, 'TestS3Layer', existingLayerArn)],
});
```

Lambda function deployed and layer integrated, Great!

Test it via AWS console test event. **No error. Works completely fine as .Net core runtime knows where to find the reference assembly files using the environment variable.**

---

Via cli command it works completely fine and via CDK it is not following approach of runtime-package-store.

What am I missing or doing wrong in my CDK deployment? How to achieve this with AWS CDK only?

If anyone could kindly provide a reference link or a code example detailing how to achieve these tasks within AWS CDK, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What issues are you running into? What does "does not seem to work as expected" and "doesn't seem to work correctly" entail?

Comment: @gshpychka - Thank you for your response. I have modified the content above. Please go through it once again. Any help would be greatly appreciated!